# ASP.Net Gridview Setting the BackColor of a Separator Row

Tags: gridview, styling

I am constructing a `Gridview` that will look like a paper based form to enable Test Results to be entered into a system.

On the form there are separator rows between rows 8 & 9, 16 & 17 & 24 & 25.

I have used the block of code reproduced below to insert the row and that is working fine in respect of inserting the row at the correct place.

My issue is that the row appears white and I want it to have a distinctive colour (at this stage it doesn't matter what the exact colour is).
The statement to set the `BackColo`r doesn't work but interestingly the Height statement does.

Can anyone suggest why the background colour isn't being set?

Thanks

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    var rownumber = Convert.ToInt32((DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "RowNumber")));

    if (rownumber < 32 && rownumber % 8 == 0)
    {
        var tbl = (Table)e.Row.Cells[0].Parent.Parent;
        var tr = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex + 1, 0, DataControlRowType.Separator, DataControlRowState.Normal)
                 {
                     Height = Unit.Parse("16px"),
                     ID = "MyExtraTr" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString(),
                     BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkSalmon
                 };
        tbl.Controls.Add(tr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the backcolor of each cell in the row

Answer (score 3):

I added the following beneath `tbl.Controls.Add(tr);` :-

```
        var c = new TableCell {BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SlateGray, ColumnSpan = gv_ReviewTestResults.Columns.Count};
        tr.Cells.Add(c);
```

and it now works perfectly.
I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it works!